# Cloud server can replace three servers?

Tags: cluster

My client requirment is for devloping the site like rapidshare.com, and his planning for manage 3-4 servers. If one server has failed due to non-space in first server then request will auto move on to next server and so on.

My question is that on my site after save any file i got a downloadable link that is mapped to physical file on server. When i click on that, the file download on my path. But the same flow can be easily managed by the clouding hosting dedicated servers.

Please reply as earliest, i have to suggest my client also.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I see no actual question here, just a number of statements.

Answer (score 1):

If disk storage is your concern, seem that you need to use distributed filesystem technologies.
I would suggest looking at getting a enterprise grade San disk array. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAN_file_system and maybe use GFS as the file system to run the SAN array.

Using it will allow you to separate the storage from your application logic, making the data just sit on a mounted drive on each servers.  That way you will be able to add drive as your need grows without affecting the cluster.

Louis